# Supervisord inet_http_server behind nginx

Tags: nginx, supervisord

We have supervisord `[inet_http_server]` running on `127.0.0.1:9001`.

When we're trying to place it behind nginx - supervisord logtail stops working.

Supervisord settings:

```
[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

Nginx settings:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
}
```

Where to dig? (Stop | Start | Restart) commands working, only tail command not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, since nginx waits until it gets the whole reply from the backend, prior to sending a response back to the client -- [proxy buffering is enabled by default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering).

This would resolve your issue:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Answer (score 6):

For me adding the following lines worked: `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and `proxy_set_header Connection "";`

My complete working config proxying supervisor output with web based tail-f working:

```
server {
  listen 9000;
  listen [::]:9000;

  server_name server.gmetri.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering     off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_redirect     default;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Connection       "";
  }
}
```