# HTTPS Configuration for supervisord

Tags: linux, redhat, process, supervisord

I've been browsing the web for articles that describe how to do it, but I couldn't find anything. The develop documentation only makes mention of a HTTP server. Nothing about enabling or configuring the web server to run using HTTPS.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Is there anyway that anybody knows of to maybe install apache/nginx/etc on the Linux host in order run the supervisord web services? Or would I need to configure one of those to act as a web proxy to ensure at least up to the proxy my traffic will be encrypted then it will go plain text from the proxy to the supervisord host:

[Supervisord inet_http_server behind nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/568317/supervisord-inet-http-server-behind-nginx)

supervisord Version: 3.3.1

RHEL Version:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Current Web Config (/etc/supervisord.conf):

[inet_http_server]
port=***.***.10.216:9001
username=****
password=****

Comment: I imagine that since it's a Python application it might be using like the twisted library to run the web server for the application. I'm not sure if twisted or whatever library it is using support SSL/TLS at all. I would figure it would since most modern applications and plugins support SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to approach this now. Using a Load Balancer I was able to utilize it's SSL Offloading feature so that the encryption is established/terminated at the LB.